# Absolute centering inside div when document is ready

Tags: jquery

I need to horizontally and vertically center a div inside another one. So I am currently using the following jQuery code:

```
function centerCaptions() {
  $('.caption').css({
   position:'absolute',
   left: ($(window).width() 
     - $('.caption').outerWidth())/2,
   top: ($('.page-title').height() 
     - $('.caption').outerHeight())/2
  });
}      
$(document).ready(function () {
    centerCaptions();
    $(window).resize(centerCaptions);
    $(window).load(centerCaptions);
});
```

where **.caption** is the element to center and **.page title** is the container. The code above works perfectly but I am wondering why if I remove `$(window).load(centerCaptions);` I get the element vertically but not horizontally centered. I would expect just the opposite. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`.resize()` is an event handler but `.load()` can also be a function call. The doc about `.load()` precise that the parameter given will determine wich `.load()` must be called. Either the loading function or the loaded event completed. For the first case, the first parameter must be an url, for the second, it must be a eventHandler. As your are passing a funciton, I think that jQuery must be lost, and throw an exception in your console and so, don't execute any jquery at all. As your elements must be vertically centered by their own css, that's why you have this result. Remove `$(window).load(centerCaptions);` that is useless here, or edit it with the right parameters.

Waht you can do is

```
$(window).load(function() {centerCaptions(); } );
```

You will so get the desired result.

Comment: Infact I want to remove `$(window).load(centerCaptions);`but when I delete that row, the nested element remains on the left (left CSS property is 0px!). Now I've tried to add a CSS line of code (`.caption {width:100%;}`) and it seems to work.

But I am still confused because I've tried to recreate my code on [jsfiddle][1] and it works even if I don't set any width on the **.caption** element.


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/agbM4/

Comment: You don't need to specify the width of your element. What you do in the js function is enough. As your parent element is `position:relative` the child (.Caption) will be positionned relativly to its parent. In the fiddle you just given, all is normal.